# Should "ate" and "eight" be pronounced exactly alike?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, accent

Is pronouncing "ate" and "eight" differently wrong? When I say "ate" it sounds like "ate" itself and when I say "eight" it sounds like "ey-ht" is that a wrong pronunciation?  I understand pronunciation may differ from one person to another depending on the accent spoken by the person. But one of my friends told me that ate and eight must be pronounced exactly alike and if you're pronouncing them differently you are pronouncing one of the two words wrong.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done.
 Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: I can't tell what your phonetic-ish spellings mean. Can you look at a standardized spelling system like [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/English) and try to spell them that way, or suggest some words that *ate* and *eight* (or their parts) rhyme with? For me, I say both words /eit/, rhyming with words like *bait, date, gait, gate, late, wait,* and *weight*.

Comment: Good video on YouTube about how eight is pronounced in various accents https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=3pkHW24RR3A

Comment: Also related: [What AmE dialect has “et” as the past tense of “eat”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/246137/what-ame-dialect-has-et-as-the-past-tense-of-eat)

Comment: South Indian English has the “tail–tale split” in which *eight* is pronounced with /eɪ/ (a diphthong) while *ate* is pronounced with /eː/ (a long vowel). In most other dialects they should be identical (both /eɪ/).

Comment: **Please use comments only to ask for more information or suggest improvements.**

Answer (score 18):

Not necessarily. In BrE, *ate* is sometimes pronounced /et/, and the Cambridge Dictionary gives this pronunciation. Even if *ate* is pronounced like *eight*, there may well be subtle differences. In AmE, *ate* and *eight* appear to be pronounced the same. However, if you are learning English, I would recommend that you pronounce them both the same (/eɪt/).

[Cambridge Dictionary: ate](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ate)

[Cambridge Dictionary: eight](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/eight)

Comment: Some Americans pronounce *ate* the British way, but for the vast majority of us, they're homonyms.

Comment: Of course, some people in New England say et for ate. But in general, there is no difference. They are homophones.

Comment: Yes - "et" is permissible in the Received Pronunciation, and in dialects - as well as "ate".

Comment: All the dictionaries I looked at say that /et/ is fine in American English, too.

Comment: @DavidRicherby That's because we've got people using the same IPA to mean different sounds. This is a problem.  The most common pronunciation is /et/ to rhyme with *bait*, although some in the UK say /ɛt/ to rhyme with *bet*.

Comment: actually, I have never heard a British person say I ate and pronounce ate as `/et/` . It also is interesting that the link you have in your answer, both UK and US pronunciation list ate as either `/et/` or  `/eɪt/` and clicking on the speaker icon, UK will pronounce it as `/et/` and US will pronounce it as `/eɪt/`

Comment: @太極者無極而生 A BrE speaker saying "Nobody wanted it, so I ate it" would use /ɛt/. In fact, I think I would use /ɛt/ more than /eɪt/ even when the word might be in a stressed position in the sentence.

Comment: @太極者無極而生 I'm British, and I would say `/et/`.

Answer (score 13):

There are two different possible questions implied here. One is for language learners, and one is for linguistics.

The answer, for the language learner (and native speakers) of General American English and British English (RP or Received Pronunciation) is that 'eight' and 'ate' are entirely identical.

The linguistic nuanced answer is there might very well be some subtle distinctions between the two based on the usual place in a sentence (one is a number and kind of adjective, the other a past tense verb). Or there might very well be dialects or varieties or sub populations that distinguish the two. There are many distinct dialects in the UK and US (many fewer in the US). Some of them say /et/ for 'ate', and most dictionaries specify it as a mainstream alternative to /eyt/ (common enough that it is considered socially 'unmarked'

But spelling is misleading in English. For almost all contexts, these two are identical.

Comment: I think the language learners and non-native speakers like me cant realise the similarity in pronunciation as there is no "i" in "ate" for it to be pronounced as "eight". I somewhat feel its fine to pronounce "ate" as ate itself instead of pronouncing it as "eight" due to the absence of "i" in "ate" or is there any rule in english vocabulary that states both words must be pronounced identically or is it just a group of people like americans or britishers pronouncing them in a particular manner

Comment: @Xlam I think you're taking the opposite of my intention. Spelling in English is sometimes rule based but just as often is merely a suggestion. You should pronounce them identically. The 'i' in 'eight' is misleading you. You don't pronounce the 'e' in 'ate', do you? Or the 'gh'? Don't try to get the pronunciation from the spelling here. Both are pronounced '[mid front vowel][yod glide][unvoiced alveolar stop]'

Comment: @Xlam I don't know about any "rule in English vocabulary", but the pronunciation of "ate" is /eɪt/ and the pronunciation of "eight" is also /eɪt/. If you pronounce "ate" as /et/, /at/ or /ate/, or you pronounce "eight" as /eɪht/, then you're pronouncing it incorrectly.

Comment: Alright now I get it

Comment: @TannerSwett "incorrectly" ?!? The penultimate paragraph of above answer explains why it can very well be correct to differentiate between them. It is not as black and white are correct and incorrect.

Comment: Saying /et/ is incorrect is to ignore the nuance of discussion on the pronounciation of "ate", especially in BrE. See https://www.dawn.com/news/576498, for example, which seems to imply that /et/ is falling out of favour in BrE, but it's at least not so patently wrong as to not warrant discussion. Spoiler: I pronounce ate variably as /eɪt/ or /et/. This is perfectly normal in BrE and doesn't raise any eyebrows. Americans look at me weirdly though.

Comment: I once asked this very question at a social group that I go to. Only one person said /et/, and he used to be an English teacher (as well as being a southerner). All the rest said /eɪt/ (as I do, myself).

Comment: /ɛt/ (rather than /et/) is also perfectly valid RP, so it's not "incorrect".

Comment: Sorry, but every dictionary I can find gives both eɪt and et as acceptable pronunciations of "ate", in both British and American English. It's certainly correct to pronounce "ate" and "eight" the same way, but it's also correct to pronounce them differently.

Comment: @tchrist [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ate); [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ate_1) (scroll through to the section "ate in American"); [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eat) describes it as "dialectal or British" (note that their [pronunciation key](https://www.merriam-webster.com/help/pronunciation-key) says they use /e/ as the vowel in "bet"). There seems to be a lot of confusion here due to different dictionaries using different symbols, but all the ones I've linked give audio samples.

Answer (score 3):

***Ate, ait and eight*** are all homophones. 
Dictionary.com defines a homophone as:  **Phonetics. a word pronounced the same as another but differing in meaning, whether spelled the same way or not, as heir and air.**

This ultimately leads us to the result that your friend is right.

Comment: I pronounce *dual* differently from *duel*. Am I pronouncing one of them wrong?

Comment: Pronunciation depends on the speaker. As far as "duel" and "dual" are concerned, their pronunciation must be exactly same. Even Google's dictionary uses the exact same pronunciation for them.

Comment: @HarshSharma You seem to have contradicted yourself there. Either it depends on the speaker, or it doesn't. Dictionaries tend to give the most common pronunciations (except for some British dictionaries that favour RP), but that doesn't mean that they must be slavishly followed.

Comment: Pronunciation varies by dialect, and dictionaries aren't always good at documenting dialectical differences.

Comment: Both of my pronunciations of *dual* [duəl] and *duel* [djuəl] are in the [dictionary.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/dual)  So please tell me which one I'm pronouncing wrong. (American English)

Comment: @PeterShor If I had to pick I'd say *dual* [duəl].  (***ate*** and ***eight*** sound absolutely identical to me).

Comment: As a native English speaker in a country of native English speakers, *dual* and *duel* have almost never been pronounced the same way. One has a single syllable and the other has two syllables.

Comment: @PCARR The whole point is that you _don't_ have to pick. If a word can be pronounced in more than one way, there's no law that says that a speaker must be consistent, let alone that they must be consistent in their pronunciation of homophones that have more than one acceptable pronunciation.

Answer (score -3):

In texting some people write m8 for mate.

This suggests, but does not prove it, that the answer is yes.

Further elaborated. At the very least, there is one way to pronounce *ate* which sounds like *eight*, so common that made it into the 'textspeak' so that *m-8* and *m-ate* are read in the same way. 
As shown elswhere, there is an alternative way to pronounce *ate* where this is not the case but, to my best knowledge, the collective mind of the texting crowd did not go that far to convene on a shorthand *m8* for *met*.

*Save-our-souls addition: please consider the debates in the comments below before downvoting or killing this post. (Aside, thanks for the upvotes that have made my reputation stay afloat)*

Comment: Why should this answer attract downvotes? To me it seems to have the same explanatory power as "why was 6 afraid of 7? Because seven, eight (ate), nine...", a well-received answer apparently.

Comment: IMO, neither has explanatory power. Textspeak isn't regarded as "proper" English so it's very weak evidence. All you've established is that the pronunciation of "mate" is close enough to "m-eight" for the abbreviation to make sense. That doesn't answer the question of whether "ate" and "eight" have _the same_ pronunciation. Also, it could be that adding an "m" on the front changes the sound: for example, adding "bo" or "tho" to the start of "rough" completely changes the pronunciation. In this case, many people pronounce "ate" as "et", but those people don't pronounce "mate" as "met".

Comment: My answer contained a humble "This suggests, but does not prove it, that the answer is yes." I report a usage that shows that m-ate and m-8 are perceived to sound the same, with the m playing an accidental role here. Inferring that textspeak is only a mark of slovenliness is a far-fetched assumption, IMHO. Also, that English is a language whereby inferences on pronunciation can logically be drawn or dismissed based on spelling would be a novel stance. Quite often there's no other evidence than usage that justifies pronunciations: so an example of usage could indeed be sufficient to answer.

Comment: You haven't refuted any of the points I made (and note that I said nothing of "slovenliness"). Once again, you've only shown that m-ate and m-eight have similar enough pronunciations for the abbreviation to make sense. And, once again, the "m" is not incidental, because there are people who prounce "ate" as "et" but nobody pronounces "mate" as "met.

Comment: I did not feel any urge to refute your points: they can be still valid and still do not exclude that the usage m-8 and m-ate hints at the fact that 8 and ate are pronounced the same, perhaps not always but certainly not unusually (otherwise none would have ever bother to use the one for the other, with a leading m in this one case). We could discuss elsewhere how to textspeak the word 'met' if ever needed. Conceded that you said nothing of slovenliness: it was my interpretation of not "proper" English. (In other words, I am doubtful of weak and strong evidences.)

Comment: You should defend your answer in the answer box, not in comments. I am too lazy to read this thread.... well, I'm not but others will be. And thanking users for keeping your rep afloat is not the best or most effective use of space.... just saying. An answer, Kitebuggy's, which I thought was worthier, was deleted by a mod. It's now a comment.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I have made an effort to reformulate my point in the answer box, as you suggested. I still feel some gratitude for all the anonymous that saved the vessel from a volley of torpedoes: hopefully thanking them is not too bathetic (slight reformulation applied there too). Such is life, as long as it lasts.

Comment: duly noted, and appreciated;  downvote retracted :)